# Auto updation based on dropdown selection value using setInterval in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a contents continuously update  based on the value selected from a drop down menu?

```
<form> 
Update interval (in seconds): 
<select name="interval" id="interval"> 
<option value="5">10</option> 
<option value="10">10</option> 
<option value="15">15</option> 
<option value="20">20</option> 
</select> 
</form> 

<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.setInterval('window.location="";', document.getElementById('interval').value*1000);
</script>
```

I've refered this code but the problem is contents only update in 5 seconds interval (first selection in drop down), no matter what value is selected.Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `document.getElementById('interval').value*1000)` is executed on page load. Which means it's always going to have the same value: `5` (i.e. the value of the first select option). This means your `setInterval` will start on page load and will wait 5 seconds before executing its callback.

To counter that, you can use an `onchange` event and read the value when the state of the select element has change. Only then will you fire the `setInterval`, and wait for the desired amount of time.

```js
const selectElement = document.getElementById('interval')

let interval;
function redirect(interval) {
  clearTimeout(interval);
  return setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('yes');
  }, selectElement.value * 1000);
}

selectElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  interval = redirect(interval);
});
```

```html
<form>
  Update interval (in seconds):
  <select name="interval" id="interval">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: redirect is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: Hi Sowjanya, did you define a function named redirect like in the above example?

Comment: Yaa I've defined.

Comment: My guess is that you've put the above code where it's not reachable by the HTML element itself. I have have used `addEventListener` instead. I have edited my post.

Comment: Uh... you might want to store the id of the interval and clear it before you create a new one.

Comment: @Terry Do you mean ending the interval if the user changes his/her selection?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you’ll have multiple parallel timers running at the same time. Imagine if the user changes value quickly 5 times, then you’ll have 5 concurrent timers.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I'll make the necessary changes.